# I want to combine map & lambda to count the number of items in a list meeting a given condition

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, lambda, count

I would like to combine map & lambda to count the number of items in a list meeting a given condition. I tried the following code, but I got an error:

`<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

The code that I tried is as follows:

```py
x = [3,7,6,4,2,8,3,4,6,3,6,6,4,6,3,3,6,4,7,7,4]

y = 4

z = map(lambda x, y: [i>=y for i in x], (x, y))

print (sum(z))
```

The expected output would have been 10 (as 10 values in the list are greater than 4).

Comment: I suggest you write a simple `for` loop first and maybe transform it to a list comprehension once you’ve got that working, and *then* maybe think about using `map`/`lambda`.

Comment: I was able to write a simple loop to get the task done, and now I am interested in doing it through map & lambda.

Comment: Then try to write a list comprehension first. It will be simpler anyway, and it seems you didn’t fully understand how `map` works, and `lambda` neither.

Comment: Actually, the list comprehension you wrote inside the `map` is already all you need.

Comment: Please format the code within your question. When you edit your question there is a {} icon which lets you format blocks of text as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
x = [3,7,6,4,2,8,3,4,6,3,6,6,4,6,3,3,6,4,7,7,4]

y = 4

z = map(lambda a: 1 if a > y else 0, x)

print(sum(z))
```

or you cause `filter` with `len` build-in functions:

```
len(list(filter(lambda a: a > y, x)))
```

**output:**

```
10
```

or you can use a for loop:

```
total = 0
for e in x:
    if e > y:
        total += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

e.g. using map and lambda.

```py
x = [3, 7, 6, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6, 3, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 3, 6, 4, 7, 7, 4]
y = 4
z = map(lambda x: (1 if x > y else 0), x)
print(sum(z))
```

Note that you can't use `y` in your map/lambda because you can't iterate on an `int`.

If you absolutely want to use a second parameter you have to pass `y` such that it is iterable :

```py
z = map(lambda x, y: (1 if x > y else 0), x, [y] * len(x))
print(sum(z))
```

It works, but I don't think it's a good practice.